# Equinox maven dependency (for maven or gradle)

Tags: java, maven, gradle, equinox, maven-central

Is there Equinox consumable as maven dependency with maven or gradle

The latest in Central is 'org.eclipse.osgi:org.eclipse.osgi:3.7.1', while the latest seems to be 3.10 http://download.eclipse.org/equinox/

Answer (score 2):

In 2017 there was a big initiative to publish eclipse jars on maven central.

During this process some of the coordinates have changed. The newest `org.eclipse.osgi` is:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.platform</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.eclipse.osgi</artifactId>
  <version>3.15.100</version>
</dependency>
```

See for reference:

- [Bug 484004](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=484004)
- [Eclipse Neon.2 is on Maven Central](https://objectteams.wordpress.com/2017/01/09/eclipse-neon-2-is-on-maven-central/)